# Linq not found after downgrading to .net 3.5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq, msbuild

We recently tried to upgrade our software to .net 4.0.  We ran into a small snag and rather than spend the time to try to track everything down we decided to revert back to .net 3.5.

We have encountered a few issues like .resx files not properly reverting, but they have been fixed.  The final problem we have encountered is a few projects are not building via command line now (everything was before).  The error in all cases is as follows.

The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

We use Visual Studio 2010, msbuild for the command line builds, every project has been changed to a framework of 3.5.  The projects will still build in the IDE, but it is fairly time consuming for us to build them all by hand, rather than by our automated script.

It would also be worth noting that all the projects that aren't building are web projects.  Within the web.config I don't see a single version=4.0.0.0 reference.

Comment: How did you "revert back to .net 3.5"?

Comment: I guess you didn't reference `System.Core.dll`.

Comment: reverted back by changing the target framework.

Comment: system.core.dll does have a checkmark next to it when I look at the references (though I don't see it in the list)

Answer (score 2):

CodesInChaos was partially right.  While the UI showed a reference to System.Core, there was no actual reference in the .csproj file.  This had to be added in manually.  This explains why the UI would build, but the command line wouldn't.

Comment: This just fixed my problem I've been pulling my hair out most of the day to solve :p  Thanks!

It's worthy to note that Visual Studio would not let me add System.Core, and would error out if I attempted to do so--so I had to modify the csproj manually in Notepad as well.